# Using argument of outer function as global variable for a function defined inside outer function - "function factory"

Tags: r, function

Is this bad practice? It seems like a lot could go wrong here.*

I am setting the argument of an outer function to be a global variable for a function defined inside it.  I am just doing this to work around some existing code.

```
f = function(a,b){h = function(c){print(b);b+c}}
myh  = f(1,2)
myh(7)

#[1] 2
#[1] 9
```

*On the other hand, it's perfectly acceptable to write something like

```
h = function(c){print(7);7+c}
```

Comment: The structure is called function factory and is used when you want to set up some local variables by the outer function in its execution environment so that an inner function whose environment is the outer's functions execution environment can access it. So the purpose here is the local variables set up by the outer function is enclosed in an structure called closure and cannot be modified by the objects of the same name in the global environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a function that creates functions (or a function factory) is a totally acceptable code practice. See https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html for more details on certain parts of the technical implementation in R.

It is most often used if you need to create functions at runtime or you need to create a lot of similar funcions.

The function factory you have created could be considered similar to a function factory that would create different sized counters that told the user how much the amount was incremented by.

It is important to keep track of the functions you create this way however.

Let me know if you'd like more clarification on anything.

(One possible bad practise in the function you have created though is an unused argument a).